Is it possible to speed up this function?
I need to compile a function that takes 2 lists of vectors and a matrix and takes tensor products and sums them weighting with the matrix elements:
func = Function[
    {
        Typed[v1,"PackedArray"::["Real64",2]], 
        Typed[v2,"PackedArray"::["Real64",2]], 
        Typed[M, "PackedArray"::["Real64", 2]]
    },
    
    Module[
        {len = Length[M], tproduct, len1 = Length[v1[[1]]], len2 = Length[v2[[1]]]},
        
        Sum[
            tproduct = Table[v1[[i,q]] v2[[j,p]], {q,len1}, {p, len2}];
            
            M[[i,j]] tproduct, 
            
            {i,1,len}, {j,1,len}
        ]
    ]
];
cf = FunctionCompile[func];

It works fine, but if I use the old Compile:
cfC = Compile[
    {{Matrix, _Real, 2}, {v1,_Real,2}, {v2, _Real, 2}},
    Module[
                {len = Length@Matrix},
        
                Sum[
                    Matrix[[i,j]] Outer[Times,  v1[[i]],  v2[[j]]],
                    {i,len}, {j,len}
                ]
    ],
    CompilationTarget->"C",
    RuntimeOptions->{"EvaluateSymbolically" ->False, "CatchMachineOverflow" ->False,
    "CatchMachineIntegerOverflow" -> False}
]

I get better timings:
Module[
    {v = RandomReal[{1,10}, {1000, 21}], M = RandomReal[{1,10},{1000,1000}]},
    
    {
        cf[v,v,M];//AbsoluteTiming,
        cfC[M,v,v];//AbsoluteTiming
    }
]
(*{{1.96663, Null}, {1.14104, Null}}*)

I would like to use FunctionCompile, because I want to export code for Windows and Linux as well (I am using MacOs), is there a way to speed up the code from FunctionCompile so that it is as fast as the version from Compile?

Related questions on the difference in performance of FunctionCompile and Compile: (1) Compile vs FunctionCompile, (2) To accelerate FunctionCompile, (3) New Compiler Technology in V12.

<rant>
As a side note: I do not mean to offend anybody, but I find it a bit strange that instead of addressing the obvious performance problems of FunctionCompile, somebody made things worse by adding a DYNAMIC STATUS WINDOW so that we are "entertained" while we have to wait for 7 seconds(!!). (I actually feel a bit insulted by that.) That is 7 seconds for compiling a simple triple for loop in C. That would be only acceptable if FunctionCompile would optimize the hell out of the code. But it obviously does not. I guess it even pessimizes it by preventing the actual C compiler from properly vectorizing the loops.
</rant>
Back to the actual performance problem. I would recommend to simply use the following:
Transpose[v1].M.v2

That uses BLAS routines and is about 1000 times faster than the FunctionCompiled cf on my machine. Fortunately, even FunctionCompile cannot break the performance of BLAS routines, so this is the answer to your question:
func = Function[{
    Typed[v1, "PackedArray"::["Real64", 2]],
    Typed[v2, "PackedArray"::["Real64", 2]],
    Typed[M , "PackedArray"::["Real64", 2]]
    },
   v1\[Transpose].M.v2
   ];

cf = FunctionCompile[func];


Thank you so much, that is amazing. It is really shameful that I didn't realized that the whole thing was a matrix product !!! (btw, I also think that the status window is mostly pointless LOL )

You're welcome. I am glad that I was able to help.

Happy to upvote for the answer with the rant as a bonus special. Or maybe it’s the other way around.

ProgressReporting -> False will suppress the dynamic status window and save you around 100ms.
